# AngularJS ngModel in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bind, directive

I wrote my own directive to parse a input with select2 and gat data via ajax.

HTML:

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="name"
       data-ui-event="{keyup: 'searchByName($event)',change: 'searchByName($event)'}"
       ajax-select2="single" data-url="/ajax/name/"
/>
```

JS:

```
.directive('ajaxSelect2', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var reqParams = {},
            multiple = attrs.ajaxSelect2 === "multi" ||
                       attrs.ajaxSelect2 === "multiple" ? true : false;

        switch(element.prop("tagName")) {
            case 'INPUT':
                element.select2({
                    multiple: multiple,
                    ajax: {
                        quietMillis: 200,
                        url: attrs.url,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: function (term, page) {
                            var req = {
                                "val": term,
                            };
                            return JSON.stringify(req);
                        },
                        results: function (data, page) {
                            return { results: data };
                        }
                    }
                });
            break;

            default:
                alert('ajax-select2 works only with input fields!');
            break;
        }

        element.bind("change", function () {
            element.show(); //shows the input
            $timeout(function () {
                element.trigger('keyup'); //doesn't work
            });
        });
    }
}}])
```

My problem: The selected value is set to the input and the searchByName function is called, but it did not work with my ng-model. If I add another input with ng-model="name" the value should be written to this input too. But it doesn't.

**EDIT**: Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StinsonMaster/n87MG/12/)

Comment: Where are you using ng-bind?  Or do you mean ng-model? If ng-model, somewhere in your select2 callbacks, you'll need to manually update `scope.name`, or does your searchByName function already do that?

Comment: A fiddle or a plunker would help us to find a solution.

Comment: Oh shit! Yes, ng-model not ng-bind. I had just two minutes to write this. I will prepare a fiddle now.

Comment: Okay, added the jsfiddle. As you can see, all fields except the ajax-select2 generated fields are synced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!
I had to update the ng-model in the scope by hand.

```
element.bind("change", function(e) {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        scope[attrs.ngModel] = e.val;
    });
});
```

Full code example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n87MG/14/).

Comment: This code will not work with dot in binding variable, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494457/how-to-set-an-interpolated-value-in-angluar-directive

Answer (score -2):

Correct your code to :

```
$timeout(function () {
   element.trigger('keyup'); //doesn't work
}, **Interval**);
```